# NameError: name 'sc' is not defined

Tags: python

I am working on some code for Face-Recognition. I am trying to combine the csv files that I have into one file that the program will read and once it has an accuracy level of at least 0.8 or higher it will scan my face and determine my expression. When running the program it complains about the variable "sc". Before I was having trouble with the variable "capture" but I was able to fix that now I have this new error and I'm not used to using Random Forest so can someone help me out?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import path
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import variable_record
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy

os.chdir("../csv_files/")


def file_combination():
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
    combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    print("Combination is finished")


def create_file():
    print("Prepare for csv files combination...")

    # check whether the combined file is existed
    is_existed = path.exists("combined_csv.csv")

    # ask user whether he/she want to renew the file if the file is already existed
    if is_existed:
        renew = input("The file is already existed, do you renew the file? (Y/N) ")
        if renew.upper() == 'Y':
            os.remove("combined_csv.csv")
            file_combination()
        else:
            print("Program is ended.")
            exit(0)
    else:
        file_combination()
    print("--------------------------------------------")


def main():
    create_file()

    # import dataset
    dataSet = pd.read_csv("combined_csv.csv")

    # preparing data for training
    X = dataSet.iloc[:, 0:7].values
    y = dataSet.iloc[:, 7].values

    # divide data into training data and test data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

    # scaling features
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

    # train the data
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
    print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

    while True:
        # turn on the webcam and check the status
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if capture.isOpened() is False:
            print("Camera Error, please check your camera @_@")
            exit()
        
        # change the BGR frame to gray frame
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # use face_recognition library to locate the landmarks
        face_marks = face_recognition.face_landmarks(gray, None, "large")

        if face_marks.__len__() != 0:
            # calculate EAR, MAR, PUC, and MOE
            L_EAR = variable_record.cal_EAR(face_marks[0]["left_eye"])
            R_EAR = variable_record.cal_EAR(face_marks[0]["right_eye"])
            MAR = variable_record.cal_MAR(face_marks[0]["top_lip"], face_marks[0]["bottom_lip"])
            PUC = variable_record.cal_PUC(face_marks[0]["left_eye"])
            EBA = variable_record.cal_EBA(face_marks[0]["right_eyebrow"])
            CAR = variable_record.cal_CAR(face_marks[0]["chin"])
            MOE = MAR / L_EAR

            predict_data = numpy.array([[L_EAR, R_EAR, MAR, PUC, MOE, EBA, CAR]])
            predict_data = sc.transform(predict_data)
            expression = classifier.predict(predict_data)

            # transfer expression value to english
            if expression == 1:
                expression = "Neutral"
            elif expression == 2:
                expression = "Happiness"
            elif expression == 3:
                expression = "Sadness"
            elif expression == 4:
                expression = "Fear"
            elif expression == 5:
                expression = "Angry"
            elif expression == 6:
                expression = "Surprise"
            else:
                expression = "Other"
            print(expression)

            # rectangle the face
            face_point = face_recognition.face_locations(gray)
            for pts in face_point:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (pts[3], pts[0]), (pts[1], pts[2]), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                # show the result on the frame
                cv2.putText(frame, expression, (pts[3], pts[0]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1.0, (0, 255, 0), 1)

        # press q to exit the loop
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break

        # display the frame
        cv2.imshow("Expression Prediction", frame)

    # release the memory
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    exit(0)
```

Comment: The variable 'sc' is instantiated in the main() function. It is out of scope by the time you do this:- predict_data = sc.transform(predict_data)

Comment: Python is not C/C++ - you don't *need* a `main()` function. Just combine the logic you've put in `main()` with the code that comes after you call it, and everything should work as expected.

Comment: So what would I need to do? Should I move it somewhere else? @AndyKnight

Comment: So I would get rid of the main() function but the code that is inside of it I would add after the while True: ? @MattDMo

Comment: Take the code that is currently in `main()` and place it where you currently call `main()` - **before** the `while True` loop.

Comment: Notwithstanding the rather unusual structure of your code, what you could do is return sc from main() then sc = main()

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, sc is out of scope when you are calling transform.
Either you can remove main mentod and put all logic outside, or return sc from your main function.

Something like this:

```
...  
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
return sc
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = main()
    ....
```